# how to add special character "#" in django url?

Tags: django

How to add special character **#** in django url?

My code:

```
url(r'updateHashTags/(?P<id>[\w\-]+)$', views.updateHashTags, name='updateHashTags')
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with `#` with `%23` ?

Comment: my objectId starts with the # and  i have to pass the data using objectId, how can i replace it with %23

Comment: You will need to give more information. Where is the code that is generating that URL? Where is the code that is processing it?